# What is the difference between Boolean and [Boolean]?

Tags: vb.net, identifier

I ran some code through an automatic translator for C# to VB, and it translated some code like this:

```
Public Property Title As [String]
```

How is this different to

```
Public Property Title As String
```

and why do both exist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`String` is a keyword. If you want to use a keyword as an identifier, you'll have to enclose it in brackets. `[String]` is an identifier. `String` keyword always refers to `System.String` class while `[String]` can refer to your own class named `String` in the current namespace. Assuming you have `Imports System`, both refer to the same thing most of the time but they *can* be different:

```
Module Test
    Class [String]
    End Class
    Sub Main()
        Dim s As String = "Hello World"        // works
        Dim s2 As [String] = "Hello World"     // doesn't work
    End Sub
End Module
```

The primary reason for existence of `[ ]` for treating keywords as identifiers is interoperability with libraries from other languages that may use VB keywords as type or member names.

Answer (score 1):

[] allows you to use VBs keywords as identifiers, just like @ in c#. it is useless here.

Answer (score 0):

In that example, they do nothing.(*)  You can use brackets to use reserved words as identifiers, though.  E.g.: `Dim [String] as String`

EDIT: 
(*) Unless they've defined their own class called `[String]` that they could be referring to